# spring integration: consume ws sequentially or concurrently

Tags: spring-integration

I think that `<int-http:outbound-gateway />` process ws sequentially , is that the default behavoiur in spring integration?

How to consume ws concurrently ? it means that  calling ws2 does not wait for response of ws1, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use an Executor Channel [docs here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel).